# CSS - border from child element to override parent element

Tags: html, css

I have the following code snippet:

```css
h2 { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.middle-bar { background-color: #b0b0b0; border-bottom: 2px solid black; }
.middle-bar h2 { border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white; display: inline-block }
.above-main { display: inline-flex; }
```

```html
<div class="middle-bar">
  <h2>TEST</h2>
  <div class="above-main">
    <span>test test 123</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get it so that the parent (`middle-bar`) bottom-border does not pass under the `<h2>` element (so as to use the `<h2> border-bottom` for that section).

If I set the `border-bottom: 2px solid black;` to `above-main` class, it only underlines test test 123. If I set `above-main` to `display: block;` (or `display: flex;`), it acts like a `block` element is supposed to and makes a new line below the `<h2>`.

**Does anyone know how to get the `border-bottom: 1px solid white;` from the child element `<h2>` to "override" the `border-bottom: 2px solid black;` from the parent `.middle-bar` element?**

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more (or) what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the border bottom on the above-main div instead of the outer div.

Edit: as you have already tried that:
Does `margin-bottom: -1px` on the h2 solve it?

Comment: please see my second paragraph after the code snippet, I already tried,.. but thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Apologies, didn't see. I've updated with another potential solution.

Comment: yes this works perfectly! I made it `margin-bottom: -2px;` as that is the size of the bottom border. thank you!

Comment: Lovely. Might be worth double checking in all relevant browsers as it's a bit of a hack!

Comment: looks like it is not a hack, so, we're good!: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this?

```css
h2 { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.middle-bar .above-main { background-color: #b0b0b0; border-bottom: 2px solid black; }
.middle-bar h2 { border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white; display: inline-block }
.above-main { display: inline-flex; }
```

```html
<div class="middle-bar">
  <h2>TEST</h2>
  <div class="above-main">
    <span>test test 123</span>
  </div>
</div>
```